# Setting MaxRAMPercentage on container with java version 1.8.0_282

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, aws-cloudformation

I'm working with Docker and Kubernetes on AWS (cloudformation yaml)

Yaml

```
...
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "4Gi"
    cpu: "0.5"
  limits:
    memory: "4Gi"
    cpu: "0.5"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest
RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0
EXPOSE 8103
ADD myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0","-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0","-jar","myapp.jar"]
```

Follow you can find the version of java "1.8.0_282" from the bash of my pod

```
bash-4.2# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal  -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 67108864                            {product}
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1073741824                          {product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

I read this [blog](https://merikan.com/2019/04/jvm-in-a-container/#java-10) where the author has explained that *"If you are running Java 8 update 191 or later, or Java 10, 11,12, 13 etc. you must NOT use the UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap option. Instead you should use the UseContainerSupport that is activated by default."*

For this reason I have added the options "-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0","-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0" in my ENTRYPOINT instruction.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0","-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0","-jar","myapp.jar"]
```

Unfortunately the UseContainerSupport values didn't change on my pod as you can see follow

```
bash-4.2# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal  -version | grep -E "UseContainerSupport | InitialRAMPercentage | MaxRAMPercentage | MinRAMPercentage"
double InitialRAMPercentage                      = 1.562500                            {product}
double MaxRAMPercentage                          = 25.000000                           {product}
double MinRAMPercentage                          = 50.000000                           {product}
  bool UseContainerSupport                       = true                                {product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

I have also tried to add JAVA_OPTS in my YAML as following but nothing change

```
env:
  - name: JAVA_OPTS
    value: "-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0"
```

Finally the question :-)

How and where have I to set the -XX:MinRAMPercentage and -XX:MaxRAMPercentage options in order to modify the default value of MaxRAMPercentage? I want use 3Gi of memory of 4Gi dedicated (on yaml)

Thanks to everyone

Comment: As far as I know, `JAVA_OPTS` is more of a convention, whereas `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` [is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html); maybe try that one? As for the actual memory knobs you're asking about, I'm sorry I don't have more insight to offer

Answer (score 6):

Please change your env variable from `JAVA_OPTS` to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.
This worked for me with Java8.

Comment: Thanks! this is the solution for running Java 8 (openJdk) containers in kubernetes.